# Optimizing my JavaScript lodash code to perform faster

Tags: javascript, optimization, lodash

I have the below code which is working fine but it takes a lot of time for a large set of data. I am just trying to think if there is a way I can make it perform faster. I don't really have to use lodash if it can perform faster without it.
Here is my code:

```js
const stringifyDates = (obj) => _.mapValues(obj, (v) => (_.isDate(v) ? v.toISOString() : v));
    
    const generateUrl = (event, path) => {
      const host = event.headers.host;
      const protocol = event.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];
      let stageUrlPart = '';
      if (!host.includes('localhost') && !host.includes('127.0.0.1')) {
        // If we're running locally the stage isn't part of the URL.
        stageUrlPart = `/${event.requestContext.stage}`;
      }
      return `${protocol}://${host}${stageUrlPart}/${path}`;
    };
    
    const urlToErrorFile = (event, errorPath, transactionId) => {
      if (errorPath !== null) {
        return generateUrl(event, `submissions/${transactionId}/error-doc`);
      }
      return '';
    };
    
    const safeParseInt = (str, radix = 10) => {
      if (str && _.isString(str)) {
        return parseInt(str, radix);
      }
      return str;
    };
    
    const formatDate = (subDate) => new Date(subDate).toISOString();
    
    const urlToDocument = (event, transactionId) =>
      generateUrl(event, `submissions/document?transaction_id=${transactionId}`);
    
    const statusIdsToDescriptions = {
      UPLOADING: 'Uploading',
      UPLOADING_LATE: 'Uploading Late',
      RECVD: 'Received',
      RECVDLATE: 'Received Late',
      DATAREJ: 'The file is rejected for data errors',
      'DATAREJ-S': 'The file is rejected for schema errors',
      ACCPT: 'Accepted',
      XMLPASSED: 'xml schema validation Passed',
      HOLDSTRIKE3: 'Submission is on Hold Status',
      HOLD4VRESU: 'Submission is on Hold Status for invalid version',
      RELEASEBYODI: 'Submission has been released from hold',
      INTERNAL_ERROR: 'Submission had an internal error'
    };
    const isPresent = (value) => !(_.isUndefined(value) || _.isNull(value));
    const dynValue = (fieldValue, defaultValue = null) => {
      if (isPresent(fieldValue)) {
        return fieldValue.S || fieldValue.N;
      }
      return defaultValue;
    };
    
    const result = {"Items":[{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:01.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"UPLOADING_LATE"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:01.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:01.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"Uploading Late"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}},{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:02.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"RECVD"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:02.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:02.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"Received"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}},{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:05:03.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"DATAREJ"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:05:03.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:05:03.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"The file is rejected for data errors"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}},{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:10:04.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"HOLDSTRIKE3"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:10:04.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:10:04.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"Submission is on Hold Status"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}}],"Count":4,"ScannedCount":4};
    
    
    const mapSubmission = (event, s) => {
      const subMap = stringifyDates({
        ewr_id: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.ewr_id)),
        //Unique transaction id number
        transaction_id: dynValue(s.transaction_id, '0'),
        file_name: dynValue(s.file_name),
        actual_file_name: dynValue(s.actual_file_name),
        category: dynValue(s.report_category_descr),
        type: dynValue(s.report_type_descr),
        version: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.version)),
        quarter: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.report_qtr)),
        time_frame: `${dynValue(s.report_year)} Q${dynValue(s.report_qtr)}`,
        year: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.report_year)),
        upload_date: formatDate(dynValue(s.create_date)),
        processed_date: formatDate(dynValue(s.transaction_date)),
        confidentiality: dynValue(s.confidentiality_name),
        s3_location: dynValue(s.s3_location),
        error_path: dynValue(s.error_path),
        status_id: dynValue(s.transaction_cd),
        status: statusIdsToDescriptions[dynValue(s.transaction_cd)],
        doc_url: urlToDocument(event, dynValue(s.transaction_id)),
        error_doc_url: urlToErrorFile(event, dynValue(s.error_path), dynValue(s.transaction_id))
      });
      return subMap;
    };
    const event = {"headers":{"accept":"application/json","host":"localhost","x-forwarded-proto":"http","user-email":"fred@flintstones.com","user-type":"internal"},"requestContext":{"httpMethod":"GET"},"path":"/external/submissions/1","_app":{},"pathParameters":{"ewrId":"1"}};
    const sub = _.map(result.Items, (s) => mapSubmission(event, s));
      sub.forEach((item) => {
        delete item.error_path;
        delete item.s3_location;
      });
      
    console.log(sub);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to be more specific with you question. I understand you, you wanna a faster code, but you need to say which part is where the process is more slow. For example I recommend you put many `console.log(new Date.now())` and see the time diff.

Comment: I embedded your code into a runnable Stack Snippet and linked to lodash. Let me know if the output is incorrect.

Comment: I would strongly recommend commenting this code to help people understand its intended purpose. It is very hard to follow otherwise.

Comment: At first glance, your `generateUrl` function seems to be extremely wasteful. All of that logic is being evaluated against that one event object, but it's running that for every single item in the result.Items array. You can save processing time by moving that logic out of there and executing it only once before you kick off your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash is fine for its object and array manipulation helpers, but using it for stuff like `isNull` is inefficient. It's about as long as checking manually and is implemented the same way in the backend, so all you're doing is adding an extra function call for something that doesn't need to be.

So this:

```
const isPresent = (value) => !(_.isUndefined(value) || _.isNull(value));
```

is pretty pointless. `isPresent(fieldValue)` is equivalent to and slower than `fieldValue != null`. Same story with `_.isString` and `_.isDate`. I'll be removing these.

`formatDates` is expensive, and as far as I can tell, unnecessary. You want as little iteration as possible overall, and this is a step that can be done if needed during the initial pass, without requiring another one. I've removed it.

```
    sub.forEach((item) => {
      delete item.error_path;
      delete item.s3_location;
    });
```

Is this just for display to us? If not, you can merely leave these properties out of the object returned by `mapSubmission`. You skip an iteration and expensive `delete`s this way. I've done this in the code below.

```
    const safeParseInt = (str, radix = 10) => {
      if (str && _.isString(str)) {
        return parseInt(str, radix);
      }
      return str;
    };
```

I'm not sure what makes this "safe" as `parseInt` automatically converts the first argument to a string anyway. It is recommended to always specify a radix though so that part stays. I think it's safer to just return the result of parseInt - let it be NaN if needed.

Everything else looks pretty much fine. Now instead of three iterations there's only one. Here's the refactored code:

```js
    
    const statusIdsToDescriptions = {
      UPLOADING: 'Uploading',
      UPLOADING_LATE: 'Uploading Late',
      RECVD: 'Received',
      RECVDLATE: 'Received Late',
      DATAREJ: 'The file is rejected for data errors',
      'DATAREJ-S': 'The file is rejected for schema errors',
      ACCPT: 'Accepted',
      XMLPASSED: 'xml schema validation Passed',
      HOLDSTRIKE3: 'Submission is on Hold Status',
      HOLD4VRESU: 'Submission is on Hold Status for invalid version',
      RELEASEBYODI: 'Submission has been released from hold',
      INTERNAL_ERROR: 'Submission had an internal error'
    };

    const generateUrl = (event, path) => {
      const host = event.headers.host;
      const protocol = event.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];
      let stageUrlPart = '';
      if (!host.includes('localhost') && !host.includes('127.0.0.1')) {
        // If we're running locally the stage isn't part of the URL.
        stageUrlPart = `/${event.requestContext.stage}`;
      }
      return `${protocol}://${host}${stageUrlPart}/${path}`;
    };
    
    const safeParseInt = (str, radix = 10) => {
      return parseInt(str, radix);
    };
    
    const formatDate = (subDate) => new Date(subDate).toISOString();
    
    const urlToDocument = (event, transactionId) =>
      generateUrl(event, `submissions/document?transaction_id=${transactionId}`);

    const urlToErrorFile = (event, errorPath, transactionId) => {
      if (errorPath !== null) {
        return generateUrl(event, `submissions/${transactionId}/error-doc`);
      }
      return '';
    };
    
    const dynValue = (fieldValue, defaultValue = null) => {
      if (fieldValue != null) {
        return fieldValue.S || fieldValue.N;
      }
      return defaultValue;
    };
    
    const result = {"Items":[{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:01.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"UPLOADING_LATE"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:01.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:01.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"Uploading Late"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}},{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:02.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"RECVD"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:02.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:00:02.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"Received"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}},{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:05:03.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"DATAREJ"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:05:03.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:05:03.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"The file is rejected for data errors"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}},{"reporting_channel":{"S":"ONLINE"},"confidentiality_name":{"S":"Public"},"report_category_descr":{"S":"Light Vehicles"},"report_qtr":{"N":"3"},"description":{"S":" "},"report_category_cd":{"S":"L"},"report_seq_num":{"N":"999999"},"confidentiality_cd":{"S":"P"},"create_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:10:04.000Z"},"create_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_cd":{"S":"HOLDSTRIKE3"},"transaction_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:10:04.000Z"},"update_name_by":{"S":"BJ"},"transaction_id":{"S":"b58109f0-49c1-11ea-b0d8-ab4a27b07f30"},"ewr_id":{"N":"1"},"file_name":{"S":"000001L183001AP.xml"},"s3_location":{"S":"Light Vehicles/000001/2018Q3/Aggregate Data/Production and Counts/000001L183001AP.xml"},"actual_file_name":{"S":"000004L163001AP.xml"},"version":{"N":"1"},"file_size":{"N":"0"},"update_date":{"S":"2019-06-21T09:10:04.000Z"},"report_type_descr":{"S":"Aggregate"},"transaction_cd_descr":{"S":"Submission is on Hold Status"},"report_year":{"N":"2018"},"create_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"},"report_type_cd":{"S":"A"},"update_email_id":{"S":"fred@flintstones.com"}}],"Count":4,"ScannedCount":4};
    const event = {"headers":{"accept":"application/json","host":"localhost","x-forwarded-proto":"http","user-email":"fred@flintstones.com","user-type":"internal"},"requestContext":{"httpMethod":"GET"},"path":"/external/submissions/1","_app":{},"pathParameters":{"ewrId":"1"}};
    
    const mapSubmission = (event, s) => {
      return {
        ewr_id: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.ewr_id)),
        //Unique transaction id number
        transaction_id: dynValue(s.transaction_id, '0'),
        file_name: dynValue(s.file_name),
        actual_file_name: dynValue(s.actual_file_name),
        category: dynValue(s.report_category_descr),
        type: dynValue(s.report_type_descr),
        version: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.version)),
        quarter: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.report_qtr)),
        time_frame: `${dynValue(s.report_year)} Q${dynValue(s.report_qtr)}`,
        year: safeParseInt(dynValue(s.report_year)),
        upload_date: formatDate(dynValue(s.create_date)),
        processed_date: formatDate(dynValue(s.transaction_date)),
        confidentiality: dynValue(s.confidentiality_name),
        status_id: dynValue(s.transaction_cd),
        status: statusIdsToDescriptions[dynValue(s.transaction_cd)],
        doc_url: urlToDocument(event, dynValue(s.transaction_id)),
        error_doc_url: urlToErrorFile(event, dynValue(s.error_path), dynValue(s.transaction_id))
      };
    };
    
    const sub = result.Items.map(s => mapSubmission(event, s));
    console.log(sub);
```

Everywhere lodash was used turned out to be entirely unnecessary, so you can remove it if you want. I'm not sure how much more performant you can get with this - if there are still issues, you might have to turn to caching solutions and the like.